# How can I fill a list on sheet1 with values of sheet2 in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the following 2 worksheets in the same Excel document:

`sheet1:`

```
       A           B                  C
 1 Extension   File Type       File Description
 2 .a01
 3 .a1wish
 4 .a2m
```

`sheet2:`

```
       A           B                  C
 1 Extension   File Type       File Description
 2 .a          Developer       Static Library
 3 .a00        Compressed      ALZip Second Split Archive File
 4 .a01        Compressed      ALZip Third Split Archive File
 5 .a02        Compressed      ALZip Fourth Split Archive File
 6 .a1wish     Data            Audials Wishlist File
 7 .a26        Game            Atari 2600 ROM
 8 .a2c        3D Image        Alice Object File
 9 .a2l        CAD             ASAP2 ECU Description File
10 .a2m        Audio           AdLib Tracker 2 File
```

I need to fill the cells `sheet1.B2 : sheet1.C4` with values taken from `sheet2`. So for instance `sheet1.row2` would have to be filled according to the `.a01` extension:

```
       A           B                  C
 1 Extension   File Type       File Description
 2 .a01        Compressed      ALZip Third Split Archive File
```

I think I need `VLOOKUP` for this but can't figure out how to apply it. Now use `=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!A2:C10;1)` for cell `Sheet1.B2` and pulled it right and down. I get values but the wrong values! For instance, `Sheet1.row2` now looks like

```
       A           B                  C
 1 Extension   File Type       File Description
 2 .a01        Compressed      AdLib Tracker 2 File
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A2:C10, 2, FALSE)` for column B, and `=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A2:C10, 3, FALSE)` for column C.

Because you didn't 'lock' your reference columns with dollar signs, it did a `VLOOKUP` on column B of sheet 2, rather than column A.